# Disable duplicate WC product category URLs

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, slug

WC generates duplicate URLs when using category slugs.

Example:
demoshop.com/cat-1/product-a

The same product can be accessed from any URL if slug "cat-1" is modified, e.g.:
demoshop.com/modified/product-a will lead to a status code 200 as well.

From a SEO perspective this is not preferrable and I would like to modify the behaviour as follows:
If the product page is accessed via the correct url a 200 is sent.
If the product page is accessed via any other url a 301 to the correct url is sent.

If the product has muliple categories assigned, the primary one should be considered.

Any hints how to realize that?

Comment: did you disable canonical URL redirects? WP automatically performs 301 redirects via `redirect_canonical` internally, though it will not do this for archives, and google won't issue SEO penalties for archive pages otherwise the search feature of a site would be disastrous for SEO, assuming you're not listing products in their entirety along with content on your archives/listings

Comment: No, nothing has been disabled. 
You are right, is is performing redirects for some base slugs as /shop/ for example. It is also performing redirects for blog posts where the post category slug has been altered.
But even on a fresh install it is not performing redirects for single product pages with altered category slugs as part of its url.

Comment: are you sure this isn't a WooCommerce specific thing? This site is for general WP questions, not 3rd party plugins

Comment: Possibly yes, will check. Maybe my fault. Thanks.